# Upgrading the OS on a compute engine instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

What is the best way to upgrade the OS on a compute engine instance? Is there any magic process that makes it easy?

On the edit instance page, I see the option to change the capacity of the boot disk but not the OS-type, etc. I haven't done such OS upgrade and am looking for any help I can get on it from anyone who has done it before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Currently at the GCP console/CLI level, you're not able to upgrade the OS. However at the VM level it is possible to upgrade the OS. You'll need to find out the Linux distribution which you're using and if upgrading it on the spot is supported. I'd like to mention that Upgrading Windows OS is not supported.

Alternatively, you can also do the following:
1) Create a snapshot of your current instance
2) Spin up a VM with the upgraded OS 
3) Mount the snapshot disk into the new VM.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Will try to relook into the matter with your inputs.